# How to get row's column value from datatable to textbox after double click on datagridview row without using properties

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable, textbox

I am working on windows form application.

It contains two form MainForm - Test and childForm - Search

Search form has dataGridView control.It contains columns like SrNo, TypeNo, TestEngineer and Date. And Test form contains textBoxes tb_SerialNo, tb_TypeNo, tb_TestEngineer, datTimePicker for date.

My main Question is when I double click Row from datagridview, I want SrNo column value from that row in textbox tb_SerialNo. Same for all.

I resolved this issue by using properties.But my senior said, not to use properties if you have datatable. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

mainForm - Test Code

```
private void SearchToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SearchTest Search = new SearchTest();
    Search.ShowDialog();
    dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "";

}
```

ChildForm - SearchTest:

```
public partial class SearchTest : Form
{
    public SearchTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Test.dt;
        this.dataGridView1.Sort(this.dataGridView1.Columns["SrNo"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

    }


    private void btn_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        string str1 = dateTimePicker2.Text;

        string dtFilter = string.Format("[Date] >= '{0} ' AND [Date] <= '{1} '", str, str1);
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = dtFilter;
    }

    private void tb_SearchSrNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb_SearchSrNo.Text) ?
                "SrNo IS NOT NULL" :
                String.Format("SrNo LIKE '{0}%' OR SrNo LIKE '{1}%' OR SrNo LIKE '{2}%'", tb_SearchSrNo.Text, tb_SearchSrNo.Text, tb_SearchSrNo.Text);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }

    private void SearchTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        groupBox1.Enabled = false;
        groupBox3.Enabled = false;
        cb_Filter.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(cb_Filter_MouseWheel);
    }

    private void cb_Filter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cb_Filter.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            groupBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            groupBox3.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    void cb_Filter_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
    }



    private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you close the search form after double click on the row? I mean are you going to use a `ShowDialog`? or search form is always open?

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei - Yes. When I double click on row, the Search will get close and Textboxes will get the respective value of columns in row.

Comment: To get information from the dialog you need to make `DataGridView` publicly accessible or define a public property to expose selected `DataRow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information from the dialog, you need to expose `DataGridView` or the selected `DataRow`.

**Using a property**

If you decide to expose a property rather than exposing `DataGridView`, first create a property:

```
DataRow currentRow = null;
public DataRow CurrentRow 
{
    get 
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
            currentRow = ((DataRowView)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Row;
        return currentRow;
    }
}
```

Then use it this way:

```
using (var searchForm = new SearchForm())
{
    searchForm.ShowDialog();
    var currentRow = searchForm.CurrentRow;
    if(currentRow != null) 
    {
        //You can find fields from the data row here:
        //string someField = (string)currentRows["someField"];
        //string someField = currentRows.Field<string>("someField");
    }
}
```

**Exposing DataGridView**

If for any reason you decided to expose `DataGridView`, in the designer of search form, set `Modifiers` property of the `dataGridView1` to `public` and then use it this wayL

```
using (var searchForm = new SearchForm())
{
    searchForm.ShowDialog();
    DataRow currentRow = null;
    if (searchForm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
        currentRow = ((DataRowView)searchForm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Row;
    if(currentRow != null) 
    {
        //You can find fields from the data row here:
        //string someField = (string)currentRows["someField"];
        //string someField = currentRows.Field<string>("someField");
    }
}
```

**Note**

If you need to detect if the user closed the dialog by double click or by pressing the close button, it's better to set dialog result when closing in double click:

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Then when showing the dialog, check the dialog result first:

```
if(searchForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //The user closed the dialog by double click on row
}
```

Comment: I tried both ways. Using this I get the data after selecting row not after double click. User should double click on row then he will get the data in textbox else not.

Comment: You told us you show the dialog as modal and close it after selecting a row. Above solutions show you how to get the selected row after closing the dialog.

Comment: Actually I meant, i won't close the form. It will automatically close after double click on row

Comment: So apply what I said in the note part and let me know if you have any question about it.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei - In above solution, values are taking from datagridview row not from datatable..I don't want to use datagridview row because its giving me a problem while using datatime.

Comment: No. The values are getting from the data row behind the datagridview row: `((DataRowView)searchForm.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem).Row`

Comment: Ok.Actually I am facing Datetime issue. I am going to open it as new question.

Comment: OK, make sure you include enough description and a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I was able to send the data from my dgv row to my textbox by using this code:

```
public string lat;
    public string lon;
    public string resulttt;


 private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        //Sends latitude and longitude from datagridview cell clicked to their respective textboxes//
        int rowindex = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex];

        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
            return;
        lat = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[16].Value.ToString();
        lon = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[17].Value.ToString();
        resulttt = lat + " " + lon;
        //textBox1 = textBox1.Replace(",", ".").Replace(" ", ",");

    }
```

You can change the values according to your programm and change the textbox name accordign as well. Let me now if it works for you.

Comment: @Ipereira - Thanks for youe time. Actually I tried this way before. But I don't want to waste my memory by declaring variable. Because I already have datatable. I want use existing datatable row.